# Detect clicks inside a sourceful Iframe for mobile

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, dom-events, click-tracking

[image]

I have a situation here.

1. I am inside a sourceful Iframe(`id=a-sourceful-one`) AND NOT on the main page
2. My code is executing in a script (`id=this-is-my-executing-script`)
3. I have to track clicks inside another sourceful iframe (`id=track-clicks-within-this-frame-for-mobiles`)
4. I am in mobile mode

Basically, I'm in mobile mode and inside a sourceful Iframe. I want to track clicks within another sourceful Iframe whose Iframe element is accessable to me.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you can't catch events inside an iframe DOM unless you're on the same domain. You can however catch a event when clicking the actual iframe if you wrap the iframe inside a div and set the CSS property `pointer-events: none` to the iframe element.

**Something like this**

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <iframe></iframe>
</div>
```

```
iframe {
   pointer-events: none;
}
```

```
$('.wrapper').on('click', function(e) {
     // do sth here
   });
```